# What is the best way to model this grid?

Tags: python, grid, artificial-intelligence, tree-search

I am coding an artificial intelligence program to solve the following problem:

There are k robots in different cells of an m*n grid. some of the cells of this grid are poisonous (and the robots know which cells are poisonous). In every step, each of these robots can move to one of 4 directions(if the target cell is not poisonous) or stay in its place. I want to find the minimum number of steps needed to gather all robots in one cell (it doesn't matter which cell).

I want to use a search algorithm to solve this problem(like A*), but I really do not know how to model my states and more important than that, how to find the children of each node. I mean I want to consider all of the possible grids that can be reached by one step as the children of some current state s, but I do not know what is a good way to model this in python and I hope I can get ideas in here...

Comment: are you coding your own search algorithm, or are you using an off-the-shelf solver? In that case, have a look at PDDL.

Comment: No I want to implement it on my own

Comment: I would still use PDDL as the definition format for your solver, as it provides you with lots of test data sets which are available on the web.